# onsubmit return confirm go to url

Tags: javascript, html, inline

I have a confirmation pop-up for a form. The pop-up only displays if the user is not logged in.

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain.com/go-here.php" <?php if (sw::shared()->session->user_type !== 'customer') { ?>onsubmit="return confirm('You must be logged in to register for this game. Press ok to go to the login page.');"<?php } ?>
```

When the user clicks "ok" on the pop-up, I would like it to bring them to http://domain.com/log-in.php instead of the original form action destination.

Can I achieve this with inline JS?

Comment: It must be inline? Because you may need a function in there.

Comment: if it is possible.. that would be nice :)

Comment: Its possible but not a best practice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session->user_type !== 'customer') { ?>onsubmit="var conf = confirm('You must be logged in to register for this game. Press ok to go to the login page.'); if (conf == true) { console.log('said yes');} else { console.log('said no');}"
```

a confirm diaglog must be assigned to a variable so that the state of the confirm, which returns true on "ok" and false on "cancel", can be accessed.

[EDIT: answering the next bit of your question

in order to prevent the form from submitting when the submit button is hit, you are going to want to grab the click of the submit button and use the event method `e.preventDefault()`. 
However, this is tricky to do inline for a lot of reasons. if it must be inline: 
your best bet is to use a button other than the `<input type='submit' />` to submit your form. so, give your form an id so that you can grab it in the `onclick` of your button. essentially, you will have

```
<button onclick='var conf = confirm("blah blah"); if (conf == true) { document.getElementById("myForm").submit();} else { console.log("they hit cancel");}'>SUBMIT</button>
```

]

Comment: This will submit the form.. you have to return a boolean to it.